# Why does the following SQL query work, despite the syntax looking wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a lengthy SQL UPDATE query, joined across multiple tables, for the purpose of redacting/anonymizing old customer data.
As part of this process i want to keep the first segment of any UK postcodes found, so I have this query ( in the SET clause of an UPDATE query):

```
    oh.postcode = IF(oh.country = 'United Kingdom',
        IF(@cPos:=LOCATE(' ', TRIM(oh.postcode) > 0),
            SUBSTRING(UPPER(TRIM(oh.postcode)),
                0,
                @cPos - 1),
            TRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(UPPER(TRIM(oh.postcode))),
                    4)))),
        LEFT(LTRIM(oh.postcode), 2)),
```

('oh' is just a table alias)
the question is, why does this work? I draw your attention to the second line, which I would expect to be;

```
IF(@cPos:=LOCATE(' ', TRIM(oh.postcode)) > 0,
```

since the second argument to LOCATE() ought not to be a boolean expression...
or even

```
IF( ( @cPos:=LOCATE(' ', TRIM(oh.postcode)) ) > 0,
```

extra brackets around assignment to ensure the string offset is assigned, and not the result of the boolean expression???

It seems that something odd is going on here, or i don't fully understand the syntax and associativity rules here... can anyone explain what is going on?

I am not looking for a rewrite here, though if anyone know a better way to do this i would be happy to learn something, what i'm after is a deeper understanding of why the original query works, when it doesn't look like it should.

**EDIT:** Correctly Answered by Damien_The_Unbeliever, it appears that the split on space part of this query never runs, and it alway just chops the 3 chars off the end, of course i did not notice this to begin with as the end result looks the same...
I realise it's not part of the original question, but i would welcome any suggestions on the proper way to achieve this...

**EDIT2**

This works:

```
SET @pc = ' W1s 3NW';
SELECT 
    IF(@cPos:=LOCATE(' ', TRIM(@pc)),
        SUBSTRING(UPPER(TRIM(@pc)),
            1,
            @cPos - 1),
        TRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(UPPER(TRIM(@pc))),
                4))));
```

i think i forgot about mysql strings having a 1-based index...

Comment: Notes: the logic in the query here should be;
- if the country is uk, look for a space in the postcode,
- if a space is found split the postcode at the space and keep the first segment
- if a space is not found, chop the last 3 chars from the end, (uk postcodes always have 3 chars in the last segment, but first can vary in length)
- if not a uk postcode, just keep first 2 digits.

Comment: Does it *work*? Or does it "work"? MySQL has, to my mind, an unfortunate behaviour where, if it can possibly reinterpret what you've given it, including some type conversions that I would positively frown upon, it'll perform those conversions and give you a result rather than producing the error message most other SQL systems would give you. So whilst it is accepting the query without error, is it actually *doing what you wanted*?

Comment: Yes tried it with a number of different post codes.... could find one that didn't product my desired result

Comment: But would you get the same result if you just did the "chop the last 3 chars from the end" process and didn't try to find the space at all? Because that's what I think is happening. Do you have an example postcode where those two pieces of logic will produce different results, and if so (e.g. if someone has misformatted a postcode as `PO143A U`) what happens here?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, it appears that the 'chop 3 chars from the end' is always running... so what would be the correct way to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can see, we first work with this expression:

```
TRIM(oh.postcode) > 0
```

On the left, we have a string. On the right, we have a number. By MySQL's logic<sup>2</sup>, that means we should [convert both to floats and do that comparison](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).

Since most<sup>1</sup> UK postcodes don't start with any numeric digits, the conversion to float will produce a `0`<sup>2</sup>. And `0` is not greater than `0`. This expression will always (absent a really screwed up attempt at a UK postcode) be false. But even if that was true, we now come to:

```
LOCATE(' ', <boolean>)
```

Well, that's no good. [`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) wants a string, but we have a boolean. That's okay though. By MySQL logic<sup>2</sup>, we'll convert `false` (not sure if it goes via a numeric conversion or direct) to the string `0`, and we'll convert `true` to `1`.

Since neither `0` nor `1` ever contain a space, `LOCATE(' ',<'0' or '1'>)` is always going to return 0, so that's what's always assigned to `@cPos`, and since that assignment is then used as the truth value for the inner [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), we never use the expression in the second parameter and always use the third, which is just using the simple "chop" heuristic rather than trying to work with a space.

---

I *think* that you would get the correct-ish behaviour just by removing the `> 0` comparison entirely and just leave the `TRIM` result as the second parameter to `LOCATE`.

---

<sup>1</sup>I am also based in the UK :-)

<sup>2</sup>You may be able to infer from my tone. I am *not* a fan of MySQL's logic. I'd far rather have a honking error stuck in my face that I can fix in seconds by adding an explicit type conversion *if that's what I really intended* rather than all of the conversions that MySQL will assume.

Comment: spot on! this indeed answers my original question why it doesn't work!
evidently i need to revisit that conditional.... I know its not part of the original question but,i would welcome any suggestions on how to go about this properly..

Comment: @a.cornforth - did you see the minor addition at the end where I suggest what I think should make it work.

Comment: yes thankyou, i am experimenting with that now... it seems to result in an empty string, but that could be a problem with the string manipulation part...